# Preview react component at different media queries

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive-design, media-queries

I want to be able to preview a react component on a page at different viewport widths to trigger different CSS media queries. This is for a component library, and I want to be able to show developers what the component will look like at different screen sizes.

Any strategies on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

CSS media queries take account of client window with, if you want to show the behavior of component by resizing the browser window you won't need to do anything different. However, if you are looking to place your component in a container within the browser (like some `div`) and allow developers to resize that container to see the behavior, they you might need to replicate the media queries behavior on that container. First you will need to make that container resizable. After that you will need to listen to that `resize` event and then apply relative classes to that container according to the width of container.

You can use this plugin to make container resizable https://github.com/STRML/react-resizable and then use `onResize` event to apply appropriate css classes to show the behavior according to the width of container

Comment: I don't want to have to resize the window. I dont think resizable would work because you are just resizing the container, not the actual view width of the browser, which triggers the media queries.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the rule `@media` to define what css properties are used at which screen size, here is a guide by W3schools [CSS @media rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)